# Can't display flash notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am unable to display `notice` variable in my template. Code is below:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery
  skip_before_filter :require_login, :except=>[:list,:add,:delete,:update]
  def add
  end

  def delete
  end

  def update
  end

  def list
  end

  def login
  end

  def logout
  end

  def isloggedin
    login = params[:login].to_s
    password = params[:password].to_s
    logged_in = User.where(:user_name => login,:password => password).limit(1)
    if not logged_in.blank?
      session[:userinfo] = logged_in
      redirect_to '/event/list'
    else

      flash[:notice] = 'Unable to login'
      redirect_to '/user/login'
    end

  end
end
```

**Template file**

```
<div><%= notice %></div>
```

Comment: Change template file code to this: `<div><%= flash[:notice] %></div>` and then try again.

Comment: No luck. I can't see it

Comment: Did you make sure that the condition go through `else` where you are setting `flash[:notice] = 'Unable to login'` when you tried? Also, you can just do: `redirect_to '/user/login', notice: 'Unable to login'` instead of writing in two lines.

Comment: Yes it is in right code block.

Comment: I think the method `isloggedin` is not called. Please, you must check your routes.

Comment: it is definitely being called because it is a POST method. Another thing is that I can't print session variable either. Is it some config issue?

Answer (score 2):

Add this into your template file:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
   <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

So when your run your code next time key is replace with "notice" and value with "unable to login"

Hope this help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was because I was getting error `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`. I added following input field in form and it started showing message:

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" />
```